# Efficient storage in MYSQL, for Hexidecimal (Or binary)

Tags: mysql, database, binary, hex, storage

I am creating a database to store food orders, and I am considering the most efficient ways for storing it. And I figured that hexidecimal is the most efficient storage mechanism.

A food order would include any number of food item, plus any additions to each food item.

So, a cheese burger with extra cheese, and a pizza with extra peperoni could be stored as

300050AF200010F

Where as the 'F' serves as the comma, to separate the food items, and the very first values '3', and '2', correspond the the food item, all the values in the middle, represent the various toppings, and choices of each item.

So it can be seen as
300050AF //Cheese burger
200010F //Pizza
500210B0F //any possible additional food items, along with topping choices for this order

The food item can be different lengths, because of the 'F' comma, as some items have much more topping choices than others

First question is, is this the most efficient means of storage?

Second question is that MYSQL doesnt seem to have a hexadecimal datatype, so I would have to store it as binary, if so, what is the most efficient way to convert various values from real data to and from binary (Javascript?), and how efficient is MySQL binary storage?

Also, how would an ENUM or set compare as data storage medians?

Comment: Jay, don't go down this route bro !

Answer (score 2):

Disk space is cheap:   I think you are worrying too much about "optimal" storage.   Optimal storage is not only that that consumes the least space, but allows others browsing your tables or programming your database to understand and correctly manipulate the data.

Hexadecimal is not a storage mechanism, but rather a representation of numeric data.   However you might show a number in hexadecimal, the binary representation is more "efficient".   For example:  the value 255 can be stored in a byte, or represented as "255" in decimal, or "FF" in hex   (or "377" in octal).

However, what you're doing is not representing data in hexadecimal:  you are proposing a code that uses letters "A" - "F".    Hexadecimal "F" is 15, not a comma.

It would be helpful to know what you're trying to accomplish.   If you're trying to learn database programming, you're off on the wrong track:  use the facilities of the tool you're trying to learn, don't fight them.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with others. This is really overkill for the performance it may offer.

Also storage optimisation comes with read trade off. so queries like checking for status of order etc are not going to be optimal.

Considering that you have a food app, you are likely to have many orders and querying through them could become nightmare as you grow.